# how to check schema is in sync with classes generated with XSD.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I am using classes generated with XSD.exe from schema(xsd file) for serializing/deserializing XML. Recently I had some issues becasue the schema changed but I missed to regenerate the classes.

I am wondering what is the best way to make sure the schema and classes are in sync? How can I check this in runtime and compiletime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate classes according xsd file in Pre-build event command line of build events page of project properties. In this way, classes is always sync with schema.

Here are some useful link:
[Pre-build Event/Post-build Event Command Line Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[How to: Specify Build Events (C#, J#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, this will do for compile time checking. However it is nicer if I get a build error saying the cs file is not in sync with the XSD instead of actually replacing the file.Also, when the application runs it will download XSD from a server-how could I check that?

Comment: I can't figure out better way then write a small tool to serializing a xml file then validate it with xsd file. but it still will be done in pre-build/post-build event. Why don't just generate class straight way.

Comment: @findcaiyzh- yes, I think you are right. I will generate the classes and check. I was (foolishly) thinking about a run time check.